# How to re-generate deleted sequence numbers in hibernate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

As we know the below hibernate annotation generates a new number each time from the sequence starting from 1. Consider a situation wherein i have a set of records with ids(1-5).Now a record is deleted from the table which had id as 3. If we see number 3 is missing from the sequence 1-5 now because of the operation. I have a requirement for the sequence to re-generate and reassign that number 3 when i will be adding new record in the table. How to do this ?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is a great idea. A sequence is just a number incremented of 1 each time. This allows it to be fast but already this is a bottleneck for a distributed database for writes as all the nodes need to synchronize on that number.

If you try to get the first available integer, you need basically to do a full table scan, order the records by id and check the first missing one. That's extremely costly and inefficient for something that shall be as cheap as possible.

You should view the id as a technical ID without functional meaning and thus do not care if there are holes in the sequence or not.

**Edit:**
I also would add the implications go deeper, even in term of business.

If I get an ID for a article I sell as a merchant and I model its deletion as removing the record or even better put a status "deleted" on it potentially with a date and reason for deletion, I have much easier bookkeeping. Actually, I would prefer the last design: keep the record and have a status that is dynamic and potentially with history. The item could be unavailable for 1 year and be used again if I sell it again.

If on the contrary I silently reuse the ID, then, my system may display an old bill with the data of the new article. Instead of ski boots that I don't sell anymore, it may become a PS5 or 1kg of rice. This is error prone.

This may not apply to all business cases, of course, but its better to consider this kind of usage before going with a design that delete data.

Comment: i can't agree with you more. Thanks ! @Nicolas

Answer (score 3):

I Agree with Nicolas, but Just to clarify.

You are using an "Identity" and not a "Sequence" there are some differences between them, and how are declared and used (Each database could have their propietary implementation).

A Sequence is an independent object in your database with some properties (like start, end,increment,...) and an identity is a "property" of the column that depends on how the database handles it.

In the case of sequence (and depending on the database in some identities) you could create "cyclic" sequences to repeat the numbers after the cycle ends. But never a sequence or identity scans for "gaps" in the ids. (As Nicolas said is really bad for perfomance)

But depending on how your code will work you could create a cycle in a sequence to prevent having an always increasing value. But Only you are sure that there will not be conflicts when inserting new records.